# 'Character Set Missmatch' error in a CASE statement

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the else part of Oracle case statement to return a set string value;  Field1 is a NVARCHAR2(255 CHAR)

```
select case when substr(field1, 10, 1) = 'x' 
         then substr(field1, 9, 3) 
         else '---'
       end Data
  from table a
```

Example of data

```
Row       field1
1         Current 1x1 Cost
2         Current Cost 
3         Current 1x1 Efficiency
4         Current Efficiency
5         Current 1x1 CostB
6         Current CostB
```

What I want to return

```
Row       Data
1         1x1
2         ---
3         1x1
4         ---
5         1x1
6         ---
```

Comment: You've got a random `field1` at the end of your case statement... also, this error is likely to be caused by the data-type of NAME not being a VARCHAR2 as that's what you're returning.

Comment: The filed1 Should not be there.  the case statment ends with end as Data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to cast `---` to `NVARCHAR2` as below

```
select case when substr(field1, 10, 1) = 'x' 
         then substr(field1, 9, 3) 
         else cast('---' as NVARCHAR2(255))
       end Data
  from tab a
```

Now evry value returns the same type of data

[**Sql Fiddle Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/67bad/3/0)

Comment: +1, good answer. In the future, I recommend you to use the "Text to DDL" option in sqlfiddle, it really is a time saver

Comment: Thanks.  New to Oracle been SQL Server for years.  Got to remember to cast values.